# Batch - Remove file-ending (that contains an asterix) from path

Tags: batch-file

I need a way of removing the file-ending from a path, but I'm unable to do it if the file-ending contains an asterix, e.g. *.xsd , Any ideas on how to do this?

Sample batch script:

```
SET xsd_path=xsd\file.xsd  REM This does work
SET xsd_path=xsd\*.xsd     REM This does not work

FOR %%i IN ( "%xsd_path%" ) DO ( set xsd_filepath=%%~pi )
ECHO "Filepath: %xsd_filepath%"
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this question.  I can't make that *not* work.  Maybe your file path contains parentheses or an ampersand or some other character that's breaking the `for` loop?  Try `for %%I in ("%xsd_path%") do set "xsd_filepath=%%~pI"`.  If you `set "variable=value"` you avoid such problems.

Comment: @rojo - The simple FOR will attempt to iterate all files that match the file mask, and will have zero iterations if there are no matching files. So it fails if there are no files, and is inefficient if there are many files. Switching to FOR /F solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
SET "xsd_path=xsd\file.xsd"
SET "xsd_path=xsd\*.xsd"

FOR /f %%i IN ( "%xsd_path%" ) DO ( set "xsd_filepath=%%~dpi" )
ECHO "Filepath: %xsd_filepath%"
pause
```

Note that I also put quotes around your set statements, so trailing spaces don't get added to the variable. You also misspelled `xsd_filepath` with an extra `h`.